# Bootstrap Dual Listbox : How to Limit Selected Option

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, listbox

I'm using [Bootstrap Dual Listbox](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Dual-Select-Boxes-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Dual-Listbox.) to help user choose some option. 
 You can see I have add the plugin on my project. It's success. But i got a problem when try to make a limit when user choose the option.

Example:
There are some option, like:

- Apple
- Mango
- Orange
- Melon
- Guava

User must choose 3 option. You can't choose 1,2,4, or 5.

The problem is about to limit the option can be choose. By default, the user is not limited to choose.

This is some of my code:

```
<script src="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>assets/js/plugins/dual/dist/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.js"></script>
<link href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>assets/js/plugins/dual/dist/bootstrap-duallistbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

<div id="addimeiform" class="box-content form-horizontal">
    <select multiple="multiple" id="imei_multi" name="duallistbox_demo1">
        <?php
             while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                 echo "<option>".$row['imei']."</option>";
             }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
    var demo1 = $('[name=duallistbox_demo1]').bootstrapDualListbox();
</script>
```

If you have same problem, let share here. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: What's your problem? Have you tried anything? Show us some code and HTML, please..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use event `change`
2. Count the selected values
3. If there are more than three deselect the rest
4. Use function `refresh`

---

```
demo2.on('change', function(){
    var size = demo2.find(":selected").size();
    if(size > 3){
        demo2.find(":selected").each(function(ind, sel){            
            if(ind > 2)
                $(this).prop("selected", false)
        })
        demo2.bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true);
    }
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7018vhk8/)